# Creating a laravel ACL section

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, acl

I'm busy creating a section where a super admin can say what user can access specific areas.
The problem I'm having is getting the link to not be there if the user can't access it.

For example: I have a user that is a super admin and that user can access everything. So a new user is created and the user is called a normal user and the normal user can only access the list of groups that is available and can only edit, but he can't delete or add a new group.

So for this example I would need the delete and add group links to not be there.

I got quite a bit of code so I'm only putting up what I think is relevant.
If there is anything else that you would like me to put up, please let me know.

This is my routes.php

```
Route::group(["before" => "guest"], function () {
$resources = Resource::where("secure", "=", false)->get();

foreach ($resources as $resource) {
  Route::any($resource->pattern, [
    "as"   => $resource->name,
    "uses" => $resource->target
  ]);
}
});

Route::group(["before" => "auth"], function () {
$resources = Resource::where("secure", "=", true)->get();

foreach ($resources as $resource) {
  Route::any($resource->pattern, [
    "as"   => $resource->name,
    "uses" => $resource->target
  ]);
}
});
```

This is my helpers

```
<?php

if (!function_exists("allowed"))
{
function allowed($route)
{
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        foreach (Auth::user()->groups as $group)
        {
            foreach ($group->resources as $resource)
            {
                if ($resource->name == $route)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

This is my filters

```
Route::filter("auth", function () {
if (Auth::guest()) {
return Redirect::route("user/login");
} else {
foreach (Auth::user()->groups as $group) {
  foreach ($group->resources as $resource) {
    $current = Route::currentRouteName();

    if ($resource->name === $current) {
      return;
    }
  }
}

return Redirect::route("user/login");
}
});

Route::filter("auth.basic", function () {
  return Auth::basic();
});
```

This is my group index.blade.php

```
@extends("layout")
@section("content")
@if(count($groups))
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach($groups as $group)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ $group->name }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ URL::route("group/edit") }}?id={{ $group->id }}">edit</a>
                    <a href="{{ URL::route("group/delete") }}?id={{ $group->id }}" class="confirm" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this group?">delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
@else
    <p>There are no groups.</p> 
@endif
<a href="{{ URL::route("group/add") }}">add group</a>
@stop
@section("footer")
@parent
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/layout.js"></script>
@stop
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the `$route` parameter in the `allowed` helper a Laravel Route instance? Or simply the current URL?

On the latter, you could do something like this in `routes.php`:

```
if (allowed(Request::url())) {
    Route::group(["before" => "auth"], function () {
    $resources = Resource::where("secure", "=", true)->get();

    foreach ($resources as $resource) {
        Route::any($resource->pattern, [
            "as"   => $resource->name,
            "uses" => $resource->target
        ]);
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: The $route in allowed is a Laravel Route instance

Comment: @Niks: You can only get the current route instance AFTER the routing has been done. So you either have to check allowed by URL or you have to make a Laravel route instance manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel 4.2 try to restore the default filter and it should work.

I'm having the same issue, & I believe it's from:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
```